# Join column names in output with symbol

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

[image]

I want to join two column names in output to get parseble sting "**2014-02-21T20:38:40.56**"

Here is what I do:

```
SELECT id, date+time AS date
FROM table
```

And that's what I get:

[image]

**How do I join names with "T" symbol instead of space in between?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id, date||'T'||time AS date
FROM table
```

Comment: Nope. Error: operator is not unique: date + unknown

Comment: I don't know about PostgreSQL, but in other RDBMS, the output of this depends on the language/locale settings - it might make sense to convert date + time into strings with a fixed format (e.g. ISO).

Comment: js parses "2014-02-21T20:38:40.56" with a pleasure